# Multiple forms on a single MVC page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is a screenshot of my page. It has 3 tabs - Details, Users and Rights. Each tab has its own submit button which I need to fire different code within the controller (of which there is no code as of yet).

[image: Screenshot of application]

My question is, how to I have 3 separate forms on a single MVC page and how do I get each Submit button to run the respective code?

**View**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
    <!-- BEGIN INLINE TABS PORTLET-->
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-title">
            <h4><i class="icon-user"></i></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span8">
                    <!--BEGIN TABS-->
                    <div class="tabbable custom-tab">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1_1" data-toggle="tab">Role Details</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab_1_2" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab_1_3" data-toggle="tab">Rights</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "RoleController", FormMethod.Get, new { }))
                                {
                                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
                                    <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <div class="span3">
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoleName)</label>
                                                <div class="controls controls-row">
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RoleName)
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleName)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</label>
                                                <div class="controls controls-row">
                                                    @Html.TextArea("Description", Model.Description, new { @cols = 400, @rows = 10 })
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />  
                                }
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("UsersForRole", "RoleController", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
                                {                                    
                                    <!-- BEGIN DUAL SELECT-->
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTk5MjI0ODUwOWRkJySmk0TGHOhSY+d9BU9NHeCKW6o=" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <table style="width: 100%;" class="">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="width: 35%">
                                                    <div class="d-sel-filter">
                                                        <span>Filter:</span>
                                                        <input type="text" id="box1Filter" />
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="box1Clear">X</button>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <select id="box1View" multiple="multiple" style="height: 300px; width: 75%" runat="server">
                                                    </select><br />

                                                    <span id="box1Counter" class="countLabel"></span>

                                                    <select id="box1Storage">
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 21%; vertical-align: middle">
                                                    <button id="to2" class="btn" type="button">&nbsp;>&nbsp;</button>

                                                    <button id="allTo2" class="btn" type="button">&nbsp;>>&nbsp;</button>

                                                    <button id="allTo1" class="btn" type="button">&nbsp;<<&nbsp;</button>

                                                    <button id="to1" class="btn" type="button">&nbsp;<&nbsp;</button>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 35%">
                                                    <div class="d-sel-filter">
                                                        <span>Filter:</span>
                                                        <input type="text" id="box2Filter" />
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="box2Clear">X</button>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <select id="box2View" multiple="multiple" style="height: 300px; width: 75%;">
                                                        @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
                                                        {
                                                            <option>@Html.DisplayFor(model => user.SurnameFirstName)</option>
                                                        }
                                                    </select><br />

                                                    <span id="box2Counter" class="countLabel"></span>

                                                    <select id="box2Storage">
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mtop20">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- END DUAL SELECT-->
                                }
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_3">
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("RightsForRole", "RoleController", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
                                {                                    
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Right Name</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var right in Model.Rights)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => right.RightName)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => right.Description)</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="success-toggle-button">
                                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => right.Assigned, new { @class = "toggle" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--END TABS-->
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreated)</label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)</label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastUpdated)</label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastUpdated)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastUpdateBy)</label>
                        <div class="controls controls-row">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastUpdateBy)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UsersForRole controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UsersForRole(RoleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Just create three forms, each pointing back to where you want the call to go when the user presses the SUBMIT button? Looks like you're already doing that so what is the problem?

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I have added my UsersForRole controller, when a breakpoint is on the IsValid line, it does not get hit.

Comment: is your controller named `RoleController` or `UsersForRoleController`? That could be an issue.

Comment: RoleController, it has an ActionResult called UsersForRole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you may have something wrong in this line:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("UsersForRole", "RoleController", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
```

Controler name in the `Html.BeginForm` shoudl be only `Role` unless your controller name is`RoleControllerController?

Comment: Thats worked, I have replaces RoleController with Role.#

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing looks fine, you just need to add the other Actions in your controller...

Details

RightsForRole

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Partial Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieved the multiple form inside one form by only using three different Pages(Actions) and use tab as Actionlink. On the Actionlink you call the respective Action.

In your case there will be problem when you will post the form.

Otherwise you should use JQuery to achieve this situation.

Comment: There are no embedded forms here